# API Platform custom controller return error 500 "Controller [name] does neither exist as service nor as class"

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony5

I would like to register a user from my react frontend to my symfony/apiplatform API.
I got inspiration from the documentation of API Platform [Creating Custom Operations and Controllers](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/)

I created a specific route for the registration `/api/register`.

My user entity :

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName;
use App\Controller\RegisterController;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=UserRepository::class)
 * @ApiResource(
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"user:read"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"user:write"}},
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "get",
 *          "post",
 *          "register" = {
 *              "method" = "POST",
 *              "path" = "/register",
 *              "controller" = "RegisterController::class",
 *          }
 *      }
 * )
 */
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @Groups("user:read")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     * @Groups("user:read")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @Groups("user:write")
     * @SerializedName("password")
     */
    private $plainPassword;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $pseudo;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, nullable=true)
     * @Groups({"user:read", "user:write"})
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="date", nullable=true)
     */
    private $birthday;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32, nullable=true)
     */
    private $surname;
```

> I don't show the getters and setters for more visibility.

My specific controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Attribute\AsController;

#[AsController]
class RegisterController extends AbstractController
{
    private $managerRegistry;
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $managerRegistry)
    {
        $this->managerRegistry = $managerRegistry;
    }

    public function __invoke(User $data): User
    {

        var_dump("I'm in RegisterController");
        return $data;
    }
}
```

> As it's extended from AbstractController, the controller is autowired from symfony kernel according to [Symfony 5.3 - How to Define Controllers as Services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html)

Here is my services.yml :

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices.html#use-parameters-for-application-configuration
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Tests/'

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
```

As you can notice, I don't exclude "Controllers"

Here is my `php bin/console debug:router`

```
 ------------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -------------------------------------
  Name                            Method   Scheme   Host   Path
 ------------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -------------------------------------
  _wdt                            ANY      ANY      ANY    /_wdt/{token}
  _profiler_home                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/
  _profiler_search                ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search
  _profiler_search_bar            ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/search_bar
  _profiler_phpinfo               ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/phpinfo
  _profiler_search_results        ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/search/results
  _profiler_open_file             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/open
  _profiler                       ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}
  _profiler_router                ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/router
  _profiler_exception             ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception
  _profiler_exception_css         ANY      ANY      ANY    /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
  home                            ANY      ANY      ANY    /{reactRouting}
  api_entrypoint                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /api/{index}.{_format}
  api_doc                         ANY      ANY      ANY    /api/docs.{_format}
  api_jsonld_context              ANY      ANY      ANY    /api/contexts/{shortName}.{_format}
  api_users_get_collection        GET      ANY      ANY    /api/users.{_format}
  api_users_post_collection       POST     ANY      ANY    /api/users.{_format}
  api_users_register_collection   POST     ANY      ANY    /api/register
  api_users_get_item              GET      ANY      ANY    /api/users/{id}.{_format}
  api_users_delete_item           DELETE   ANY      ANY    /api/users/{id}.{_format}
  api_users_put_item              PUT      ANY      ANY    /api/users/{id}.{_format}
  api_users_patch_item            PATCH    ANY      ANY    /api/users/{id}.{_format}
  _preview_error                  ANY      ANY      ANY    /_error/{code}.{_format}
  authentication_token            POST     ANY      ANY    /api/login
 ------------------------------- -------- -------- ------ -------------------------------------
```

You can notice that the route `/api/register` exists

It should normally works because it's the default behavior of Symfony/API Platform.
When I use postman I get this error :
[image: Error on postman]

I tried to find some solutions on internet and tried to clear cache both in prod and dev but I still have the problem.

How can I solve this error please?

Comment: Change "controller" = "RegisterController::class" to "controller" = RegisterController::class.  Right now it is looking for RegisterController and not App\Controller\RegisterController.  You can confirm the problem with debug:router api_users_register_collection

Comment: Finally, it was the right answer... I thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Cerad said in comment, I need to take off double quote.

What I replaced :

`"controller" = "RegisterController::class"`

to

`"controller" = RegisterController::class`